# Mudar o Foreground de determinados itens duma ListBox, via Style, usando um Converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tenho um `ListBox` onde a fonte da dados é uma `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Gostaria que nos itens que começassem com "ATENÇÃO" tivesse a fonte vermelha.

Eu saberia fazer isso usando um `DataTemplate`, um `Converter` e um modelo para aplicar em um `Label` ou `TextBlock`.

Mas como não tenho `DataTemplate` mudou o cenário. Teria como eu adicionar o *Binding* e *Converter* num `Setter` do estilo?

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstLog" Height="160" Width="775">
         <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <Setter Property="Height" Value="19" />
             </Style>
          </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListBox>
```

O converter sei que seria algo assim:

```
public class CorLogConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString().StartsWith("ATENÇÃO"))
             return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
             return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Coloque toda a declaração da *ListBox*.

Comment: @ramaral Já coloquei o xaml da ListBox. Não entendi o que quer dizer com "declaração" nesse contexto

Comment: Como não vi binding nenhum com a ObservableCollection pensei que não estivesse completo. Então está a fazer isso no code behind. É possível colocá-lo? É que tendo um exemplo completo é mais fácil trabalhar numa resposta.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

A solução passa por conseguir uma forma de obter o *Path* que representa o item que está a ser renderizado.

Ao contrário do que tinha dito isso é possível.

Basta não indicar nenhum *Path* na tag `<Binding>` ou utilizar `<Binding Path=".">`, o ponto representa o *path* do "*source* actual"

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstLog" Height="160" Width="775">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="19" />

            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <testeWpf:CorLogConverter/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Posso estar enganado mas não é possível.

Para fazer o *Binding* é necessário um *Path* para depois obter o *Value*. 
O problema reside aí, não há forma de obter o *Path* que represente o item que está a ser renderizado.

O único item a que se consegue aceder é o item seleccionado.

O exemplo seguinte muda a cor do texto de todos os itens quando está seleccionado um que comece por ATENÇÃO:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstLog" Height="160" Width="775" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="19" />

            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding ElementName="lstLog" Path="Items/">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <testeWpf:CorLogConverter/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Algo idêntico pode ser obtido recorrendo a um *DataTrigger*:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstLog" Height="160" Width="775" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="19" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lstLog, Path=Items/}" Value="ATENÇÃO">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas apenas os selecionados não atenderia. Postei minha solução.

Comment: Sim, sei que não atenderia, coloquei apenas para exemplificar como usar um *converter* em um *style*

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar continuando usando minha `ObservableCollection<string>` sem utilizar um `model`, bastava que no `Binding` eu deixasse em branco. Eu estava acostumado a utilizar por exemplo "`Binding nomePropriedade, Converter = ....`". Porém tive que usar o DataTemplate:

**View**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstLog" Height="160" Width="775">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource localConverterCorLog}}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**View.cs**

```
this.arrLog = new ObservableCollection<string>();
lstLog.ItemsSource = this.arrLog;
```

**Converter**

Na verdade eu precisava de vermelho quando tinha "ATENÇÃO"

```
public class ConverterCorLog : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString().Contains("ATENÇÃO"))
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<classes:ConverterCorLog x:Key="localConverterCorLog" />
```

Comment: Usando um *DataTemplate* é fácil, não o sugeri porque você disse que não o queria utilizar.

Comment: Verdade. Procurei mas na net e vi que era muito complicado, ai larguei de mão. Como disse, não sabia que dava pra deixar a tag Binding em "branco"

Comment: `{Binding}` é equivalente a `{Binding Path=.}`, o ponto indica o "*source* actual", neste caso o conteúdo do item da lista.